# How to add a TextView between Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying on a button click to dynamically add a textview with comments associated with the button. I have a button A and B. I want(when I click on A) to add a text/TextView in between the button A and B.

Here is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="A"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="B"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test...."
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button a, b , c;
        final TextView txt;
        final RelativeLayout layout;

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);


        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, a.getId());
                layout.addView(txt, p);
                setContentView(layout);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I have the following error message: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: You are trying to add textview which is already in your RelativeLayout. What is your purpose? Moving textview or adding new textview?

Comment: It's confusing, I agree. My goal is to add a new text. You could  remove the TextView out of the xml. I thought it would have been simpler if the TextView instance already was there.

Comment: Why don't you just add it as `gone` (visibility) to the layout and show/hide it from the code? It is easier, you don't need to create it programmatically to achieve that

Comment: that is what I'll do. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try.

```
TextView textView;
a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, a.getId());
    textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    layout.addView(textView, p);

            }
        });
```

than you can set any text on it.

Comment: it works. I might go to the "gone" solution easier :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) You can change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

2) Move TextView between Buttons and set visible GONE.

3) onClick() -> setVisibility to View.VISIBLE.

hope to help you.

Comment: I don't even have to change to linear. relative works well. I always wondered what "gone" meant. cool. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The view `txt` has already been added to your RelativeLayout in the XML. You don't need to re-add it to the layout, you just need to set its visibility to show it, ie

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: see question above from oguzhand and response

Answer (score -1):

If you want to place textview in between Button A and B

Xml would be like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="A"
        />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test...."
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="B"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and change your java code to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button a, b , c;
    final TextView txt;
    final RelativeLayout layout;

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);


    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
    });

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="A"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/a"
    android:text="This is a test...."
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txt"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="B"
    />
```

And in your code

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

   a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```